# Sort XML alphabetically while mantaining XSD schema validity

Tags: java, xml, sorting, xslt, xsd

I have an XML file that is valid against an XSD schema. I would like to sort it alphabetically by applying the following criteria (in order of priority):
- by element name
- by attribute names
- by attribute values

Furthermore, I would like the sorted XML file to be valid against the same XSD  schema. Is there an existing XML sorting algorithm that would comply to my requirements? If not, what would be the best technical approach to write such an algorithm (eg: use XSLT)?

Based on my previous analysis, I tried to figure out a correct approach for the "sequence", "choice" and "all" elements in the XSD but failed to succeed. I am using dom4j 1.6.1 for my current processing tasks. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: An example would be useful, IMHO.

Comment: XSLT can sort.   XSD 1.1 can constrain elements to be sorted.  The devil will be in the details, which you've not provided.

Comment: In general if you change the order of elements then it will no longer be valid against the schema, so your requirements seem contradictory. And sorting attributes by name is meaningless: attributes are unordered.